# solve differential equation $x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=2y^2+yx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this equation?

$x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=2y^2+yx$

I tried to separate variables, but I always have both $x$ and $y$ on one side of equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=2y^2+yx \tag{1}$$
Dividing both sides by $x^2$ yields
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac1x\right) y\tag{2}$$
This is the same as $$\frac{dy}{dx} - \left(\frac1x\right)y = 2y^2x^{-2}\tag{3}$$

This should look like a familiar problem now. You want a function of only $x$ on the RHS, so divide through by $y^2$ to get
$$y^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx} - \left(\frac1x\right)y^{-1} = 2x^{-2}\tag{4}$$

Now, let $v$ = $y^{-1}$ so that $\frac{dv}{dx} = -y^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx} \implies -\frac{dv}{dx} = y^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx}.$

Substituting into (4), we have

$$-\frac{dv}{dx} - \left(\frac1x\right) v = 2x^{-2}\tag{5}$$

Rewrite it in standard form:
$$\frac{dv}{dx} + \left(\frac1x\right) v = -2x^{-2}\tag{6}$$

This should be something you know how to solve using an integrating factor. If you need to me to fill in some more steps here, let me know.

You should find that $$y = -\frac{1}{\frac{2}{x} \ln|x| + \frac{C}{x}} \equiv-\frac{x}{2 \ln |x| + C} \equiv \frac{x}{C - 2\ln|x|}$$

Comment: Thanks for detailed solution, I made substitution according to hint of @lab bhattacharjee and the result is $y = \frac{x}{-2ln(x)-2C}$ , it's slightly different than yours, but I think it should be correct, am I right?

Comment: This is precisely the same as $-\frac{x}{2 \ln |x| + C}$. Note that $C$ represents a constant, which can be (arbitrarily taken) as positive or negative. Usually one wants to deal with fewer negative terms. Also, note that $2C \equiv C$ because it's just a constant, remember?

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

Divide either sides by $x^2$ to get $$\frac{dy}{dx}=2\left(\frac yx\right)^2+\frac yx\text{ which is a function of } \frac yx$$

So, we can put $\frac yx=v\iff y=vx $ to separate the variables

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.

Comment: I think I solved it with your hint: $y = \frac{x}{-2ln(x)-2C}$

Comment: @rubick, nice to hear that